# How to make a table in PDF span multiple pages and insert network images to table in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf with tables contain data from firebase firestore, and I want to have the tables span multiple pages and insert network image from firebase storage, else I can only display a limited number of rows in one page (otherwise I keep getting the error, Flutter - PDF error, the widget created more than 20 pages) and the data are disappear when i try to insert network images. Please help.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

class cobapdfya extends StatefulWidget {
  dynamic data;
  cobapdfya({required this.data});

  @override
  State<cobapdfya> createState() => _cobapdfyaState(data: data);
}

class _cobapdfyaState extends State<cobapdfya> {
  dynamic data;

  _cobapdfyaState({required this.data});

  final pdf = pw.Document();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PdfPreview(
  // maxPageWidth: 1000,
  // useActions: false,
  // canChangePageFormat: true,
     canChangeOrientation: false,
  // pageFormats:pageformat,
     canDebug: false,

      build: (format) => generateDocument(
        format,
  ),
);
}

  pw.Widget PaddedText(
    final String text, {
    final pw.TextAlign align = pw.TextAlign.center,
  }) =>
      pw.Padding(
        padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: pw.Text(
          text,
          textAlign: align,
        ),
      );

  List<pw.TableRow> getListTableRow(pw.Context context, dynamic data) {
    List<pw.TableRow> list = <pw.TableRow>[];
    list.add(pw.TableRow(
      children: [
        pw.Padding(
          child: pw.Text(
            'Name',
            style: pw.Theme.of(context).header4,
            textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
              ),
          padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
        ),
    pw.Expanded(
      child: pw.Padding(
        child: pw.Text(
          'Type',
          style: pw.Theme.of(context).header4,
          textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
        ),
        padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
      ),
    ),
    pw.Expanded(
      child: pw.Padding(
        child: pw.Text(
          'Date',
          style: pw.Theme.of(context).header4,
          textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
        ),
        padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
      ),
    ),
    pw.Expanded(
      child: pw.Padding(
        child: pw.Text(
          'Time',
          style: pw.Theme.of(context).header4,
          textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
        ),
        padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
      ),
    ),
    pw.Expanded(
      child: pw.Padding(
        child: pw.Text(
          'Description',
          style: pw.Theme.of(context).header4,
          textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
        ),
        padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
      ),
    ),
    pw.Expanded(
      child: pw.Padding(
        child: pw.Text(
          'Attachment',
          style: pw.Theme.of(context).header4,
          textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
        ),
        padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(5),
      ),
    ),
  ],
));

data.asMap().forEach((int i, dynamic item) async {
  final netImage = await networkImage("${item['photo']}"); //data disappear when i insert this

  if (i < 5) {
    list.add(pw.TableRow(
      children: [
        pw.Expanded(
          child: PaddedText("${item['user']}"),
          flex: 2,
        ),
        pw.Expanded(
          child: PaddedText("${item['type']}"),
          flex: 1,
        ),
        pw.Expanded(
          child: PaddedText("${item['date']}"),
          flex: 1,
        ),
        pw.Expanded(
          child: PaddedText("${item['start']} - ${item['end']}"),
          flex: 1,
        ),
        pw.Expanded(
          child: PaddedText("${item['des']}"),
          flex: 2,
        ),
        pw.Expanded(
          child: pw.SizedBox(
            height: 10,
            width: 10,
            child: pw.Image(netImage),
          ),//data disappear when i insert this
        ) 
      ],
    ));
  }
});
return list;
}

  Future<Uint8List> generateDocument(PdfPageFormat format) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();
    final imageLogo = pw.MemoryImage(
        (await rootBundle.load('assets/technical_logo1.png'))
            .buffer
            .asUint8List());
    final imageLogo1 = pw.MemoryImage(
        (await rootBundle.load('assets/blu_logo.png')).buffer.asUint8List());
    if (data != null) {
      pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
      pageTheme: pw.PageTheme(         
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4.landscape,
      ),
      build: (pw.Context context) => <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Column(
              children: [
                pw.Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    pw.Column(
                      children: [
                        pw.SizedBox(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          child: pw.Image(imageLogo),
                        )
                      ],
                      crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    ),
                    pw.Text(
                        "Export PDF",
                        textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
                    pw.SizedBox(
                        height: 60, width: 60, child: pw.Image(imageLogo1)),
                  ],
                ),
                pw.Container(height: 20),
                pw.Table(
                  border: pw.TableBorder.all(color: PdfColors.black),
                  children: getListTableRow(context, data).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ]));
}
return pdf.save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable that holds the network image by awaiting it..

```dart
final netImage = await networkImage('https://www.nfet.net/nfet.jpg');

pdf.addPage(pw.Page(build: (pw.Context context) {
  return pw.Center(
    child: pw.Image(netImage),
  ); // Center
})); // Page
```

Comment: i did it, but the data still disappear

Comment: Please try removing the sizedbox.

Comment: still not work, but if i delete network image the data is work fine.

Comment: Are you getting error even if you try pw.addPage?

Comment: when use pw.addPage every page is just contain 1 row of data, if i have 10 data there are 10 page created with just 1 row of data in every page.

Comment: No i am saying .addpage for image alone. Not inside the row

Comment: network image work fine when placed on outside of table